# Django ORM dealing with MySQL BIT(1) field

Tags: mysql, django, orm

In a Django application, I'm trying to access an existing MySQL database created with Hibernate (a Java ORM). I reverse engineered the model using:

```
$ manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

This created a nice models file from the Database and many things were quite fine. But I can't find how to properly access boolean fields, which were mapped by Hibernate as columns of type BIT(1).

The inspectdb script by default creates these fields in the model as TextField and adds a comment saying that it couldn't reliably obtain the field type. I changed these to BooleanField but and opened my model objects using the admin, but it doesn't work (the model objects always fetch a value of true for these fields). Using IntegerField won't work as well (e.g. in the admin these fields show strange non-ascii characters).

Any hints of doing this without changing the database? (I need the existing Hibernate mappings and Java application to still work with the database).

---

Further info: I left these fields as BooleanField and used the interactive shell to look at the fetched values. They are returned as '\x00' (when Java/Hibernate value is false) and '\x01' (when true), instead of Python boolean values "True" and "False".

```
>>> u = AppUser.objects.all()[0]
>>> u.account_expired
'\x00'
>>> u.account_enabled
'\x01'
```

Where the model includes:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    account_expired = models.BooleanField()
    account_enabled = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    # etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that only way is to subclass, say, BooleanField, and override to_python/get_prep_value functions, so the field works seamlessly with django and
your db.

Comment: Great, that solved it. Since I am using Django 1.1.1 I had to use get_db_prep_value instead of get_prep_value. See detailed solution below

Comment: I am running Django 1.3 and I have subclassed BooleanField to return True/False when it gets a Y/N in the underlying char field but it isn't working. Even though I subclassed BooleanField, the return value is u"Y" or u"N". I ran it in the debugger and it never calls my to_python() method. Any ideas?

Comment: Ron, you might want to check this metaclass https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-model-fields/#the-subfieldbase-metaclass

Answer (score 11):

This is the detailed solution from Dmitry's suggestion:

My derived field class:

```
class MySQLBooleanField(models.BooleanField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, bool):
            return value
        return bytearray(value)[0]

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
        return '\x01' if value else '\x00'
```

Fields in my model:

```
account_enabled = MySQLBooleanField()
account_expired = MySQLBooleanField()
```

Comment: Just a little thing, I changed MySQLBooleanField to HibernateBooleanField since the boolean problem is relevant to Hibernate, not MySQL. Thanks a lot for your question/answer, it helped me!

Answer (score 3):

I had to deal the same problem, but rather than subclassing the field, I extended the MySQL backend to understand the Hibernate way. It's only a few lines of code and has the advantage that the DB introspection can be made to work correctly, as well.

See it **[here.](https://github.com/specify/specifyweb/tree/master/specifyweb/hibernateboolsbackend)**

#### hibernateboolsbackend / backends / mysql / base.py

```
# We want to import everything since we are basically subclassing the module.
from django.db.backends.mysql.base import *

django_conversions.update({
        FIELD_TYPE.BIT: lambda x: x != '\x00',
})

DatabaseIntrospection.data_types_reverse.update({
        FIELD_TYPE.BIT: 'BooleanField',
})
```

Comment: @Phalgun, iv'e updated the broken link. BTW +1 for suggested solution, works great with `django 1.65` + `MySQL` + `Hibernate`

Comment: @Ben Anhalt you are my hero.

Answer (score 3):

The **django-mysql** package provides a **BooleanField** subclass called [Bit1BooleanField](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_fields.html#bit-1-boolean-fields) that solves this:

```
from django.db import Model
from django_mysql.models import Bit1BooleanField

class AppUser(Model):
    bit1bool = Bit1BooleanField()
```

Easier than rolling your own, and tested on several Django and Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on django 1.7.1 i've to change the "to_python" function because it was not working to read correctly the data from the db:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in (True, False): return value
    if value in ('t', 'True', '1', '\x01'): return True
    if value in ('f', 'False', '0', '\x00'): return False
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python Boolean type is a subclass of integer But whereas Java it is of type Bit.
So in DB for Python Boolean field datatype should be Tinyint instead of  BIT type.

Due to the above reason the application behaving unexpectedly returning `\x00` and `\x01` value.

If we add a boolean field in Django model and run the migration then migrate, It will add a column of type Tinyint instead of bit.

So updating the column type to Tinyint should resolve the issue.